# How can I parse hexadecimal string into Char in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, hex, megaparsec

I am writing a parser using megaparsec and want to parse hex number to Char.

The hex number parser should take exactly two chars and return a char that has the same numeric value.

Right now I have something like this.

```hs
type Parser = Parsec Void String

pByte :: Parser Char
pByte = chr . read . ("0x" ++) <$> count 2 hexDigitChar
```

I heard that using `read` is considered bad practice.

Is there a built-in function that does something similar to this?

Comment: Although `read` is partial, you are taking care of constructing an argument for which `read` *is* defined, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. *Any* function  is going to be partial, because practically speaking, there is no base in which an arbitrary `String` corresponds to a valid integer literal.

Comment: But, the whole point of the parser is to fail early on an invalid string, so it's providing the "guarantee" that `read` will be defined on its eventual argument.